# Izpack - Save user input variables onto a properties file not working

Tags: user-input, izpack

I have a basic requirement to save the user input variables onto a properties file. I used `${}` for substitution. This does not work for me. But I find that almost all the forums refer this as the solution. Please help on what I am missing here.

IzPack version used: 4.3.5

Thanks,
Radhika

install.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
    <installation version="1.0">
        <info>
            <appname>Flow Tool</appname>
        <appversion>1.0</appversion>
    </info>
    <guiprefs width="740" height="580" resizable="yes" />
    <locale>
        <langpack iso3="eng" />
        <langpack iso3="fra" />
    </locale>
    <resources>
        <res id="userInputSpec.xml" src="userInputSpec.xml" />
        <res id="LicencePanel.licence" src="Licence.txt" />
        <res id="InfoPanel.info" src="Readme.txt" />
    </resources>
    <panels>
        <panel classname="LicencePanel" />
        <panel classname="TargetPanel" />
        <panel classname="InstallPanel" />
        <panel classname="UserInputPanel" id="userinputpanel" />
        <panel classname="FinishPanel" />
    </panels>
    <packs>
        <pack name="Base" required="yes">
            <description>The base files</description>
            <file src="Licence.txt" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" />
            <file src="script.bat" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" />
            <parsable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/script.bat" />
        </pack>
        <pack name="Sources" required="yes">
            <description>The sources</description>
            <file src="src" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" />
            <file src="appln.properties" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" />
            <parsable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/appln.properties"
                parsable="yes" />
        </pack>
    </packs>
</installation>`

appln.properties
`${clnt.loc}`

userInputSpec.xml
`<userInput>
    <panel id="userinputpanel">
        <createForPack name="Base" />
        <field type="staticText" align="left" txt="HPCC client tool Check"
            id="staticText.text" />
        <field type="text" txt="Client Tool Location" id="clnt.loc"
            variable="clnt.loc">
            <spec txt="Default Cluster" allowEmptyValue="true" size="25"
                id="clnt.loc" variable="clnt.loc" />
        </field>
    </panel>
</userInput>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that Izpack 5 would solve the requirement. The catch was that the UserInputPanel should be invoked before the InstallPanel. The documentation was clear enough to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Even in **v4.3.5** also it is possible to get the user inputs and save them to any file you want.
Take a look at ProcessPanel as decribed here [Doc link](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Executing+a+Java+Class+with+ProcessPanel)

In that case you need to pass the user inputs as arguments to your java class and that class will do the writing file kind of stuff.